# Find the domain of the inverse function

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Given function
$$f:y=2-\arccos (4x+3)$$
find the inverse function and the domain of the inverse function.

For the inverse function I got:
$$\bar{f}: y=\frac{\cos(2-x)-3}{4} $$

Now the domain of $f$ is $\left [ -1, -\frac{1}{2} \right ]$.

What's the domain of $\bar{f}$? All real numbers?  I'm somewhat doubtful whether I got the inverse function right.

Update:

The domain of $arccos(x)$ is $\left [0, \pi\right ]$. Then if we multiply it by $-1$ and add $+2$ we get the range of $f$ is $\left [ 2- \pi, 2 \right ]$ and that's also the domain of $\bar{f}$. Correct?

Comment: Hint: how can you find the domain of $f^{-1}$ using only $f$?

Comment: Your inverse function is fine. Find the range of f then the answer would be the domain of $\bar{f}$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi updated my question. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: The domain of $\arccos x$ is $[0, \pi]$.  The domain of $\arcsin x$ is $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, you're right. I fixed it.